# What kind of syntax is (round)(myFloat) in C?

Tags: c

EDIT: Apologies for the previous mess.

I came to a code example which goes like

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int num = (round)(3.14*2 / 1.618);
        printf("test %d test", num);

        int num2 = (round)(3.0 / 2.0);
        printf("test %d test", num2);
    }
```

What does this (round) do? Is this a function invocation of the `round` function from math.h? Does this mean I am effectively invoking a function at the location of (round) pointer? Does this mean (myFun+1)(myVar) could work in some case?

Comment: Typically that's the syntax for a typecast, but no way to tell without more of the surrounding code.

Comment: Somewhere, you should be able to find `typedef .... round;`  Show the details of that code.  It is possible that `round` is a function-pointer defined somewhere.

Comment: It might be forcing a function call in preference to expanding a macro.

Comment: It's either a function call, or a type-cast. But without more context it's impossible to say.

Comment: I didn't know this, but `(printf)("abc\n");` compiles and runs with MSVC.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well the function "name" is just like any other expression (otherwise function pointers would not work), and thus could be surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: Surprising for me too, however, although there is indeed no reason against it...

Comment: ...which means that `(round)` is not necessarily a typecast. More code is needed.

Comment: Function pointers do not support addition or subtraction (unlike pointers to objects), so `(myFun+1)(myVar)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @WeatherVane `(*printf)("abc\n");` should also compile and run correctly.

Comment: @IanAbbott And thus even `(*************printf)("abc\n");`

Comment: @IanAbbott indeed it does / they do (at Ctx).

Comment: Please show also the types of `ky`, `dcty`, `ktab1` etc. But probably it's some legacy code. Best is you show a [mcve]. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600790/what-do-the-parentheses-around-a-function-name-mean  I don't feel it's a full duplicate as it deals with function definition, while this question deals with calling functions.

Comment: I've cleaned up the code example with extracted code to a new isolated c file

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to know whether the `(x)` in `(x)(y)` is a cast or a function call without traipsing through all the source files and headers to find a definition, just add more parentheses: `((x))(y)` will compile if `x` is a function and not if `x` is a type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the parentheses around a function name mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600790/what-do-the-parentheses-around-a-function-name-mean)

Comment: Note that [my suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13600790/364696) isn't asking the exact same thing, but the answers cover this case too, and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27644805/364696) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49729878/364696) about this have duped to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `<math.h>` included, `round` is a standard C rounds its argument to the nearest integer, rounding halfway cases away from zero, and returning a `double`.

Technically, `round` is a function designator: It denotes the function. `(round)` is merely the designator in parentheses. Like other parenthesized expressions, its type and value are the same as the expression inside it. So, functionally, `(round)` is the same as `round`, and `(round)(3.14*2 / 1.618)` is the same `round(3.14*2 / 1.618)`

One difference is that `<math.h>` may implement `round` as a function-like macro. In this case, in `round(x)`, the macro is expanded, and the resulting expression may be something other than a function call, or it could call a function with a different name. (The C standard requires the result to be the same as if the `round` function had been called.) In `(round)(x)`, the macro name `round` is not immediately followed by a left parentheses, so the expansion of the function-like macro does not occur. Thus `(round)(x)` calls the actual function even if a function-like macro is defined.

This behavior regarding putting function names in parentheses to suppress macro expansion is a deliberate feature of the C library (C 2018 7.1.4 1: “… Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in parentheses,…”). However, there is no apparent reason to use it in this code.